# Html table with button on each row

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table with multiple rows and one column. Each table cell has a button in it. Like this:

```
<table id="table1" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Select</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr> 
           <td>
               <form name="f2" action="javascript:select();" >
                <input id="edit" type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
               </form>
           </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to do: when one of the buttons is pressed I would like to change its value from "Edit" to "Modify". 
Any idea?

Answer (score 21):

Pretty sure this solves what you're looking for:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr><td><button class="editbtn">edit</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button class="editbtn">edit</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button class="editbtn">edit</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button class="editbtn">edit</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript (using jQuery):**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.editbtn').click(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html() == 'edit' ? 'modify' : 'edit');
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

Apparently I should have looked at your sample code first ;)

You need to change (at least) the ID attribute of each element. The ID is the unique identifier for each element on the page, meaning that if you have multiple items with the same ID, you'll get conflicts.

By using classes, you can apply the same logic to multiple elements without any conflicts.

[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tXS6w/)

Comment: Thought about giving id's to buttons, but I get this table from a .xql file that gets its elements from an xml file. So I don't know how many rows there are. Any ideas for doing this without JQuery?

Comment: While duplicate id's aren't strictly valid, they are only an issue if you want to access the buttons by id. Is the row index important?

Answer (score 3):

Put a single listener on the table. When it gets a click from an input with a button that has a name of "edit" and value "edit", change its value to "modify". Get rid of the input's id (they aren't used for anything here), or make them all unique.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function handleClick(evt) {
  var node = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
  if (node.name == 'edit') {
    node.value = "Modify";
  }
}

</script>

<table id="table1" border="1" onclick="handleClick(event);">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Select
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr> 
           <td>
               <form name="f1" action="#" >
                <input id="edit1" type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">
               </form>
       <tr> 
           <td>
               <form name="f2" action="#" >
                <input id="edit2" type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">
               </form>
       <tr> 
           <td>
               <form name="f3" action="#" >
                <input id="edit3" type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit">
               </form>

   </tbody>
</table>
```