# JQuery Grab text from td when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework

Using the Scala Play Framework in case there is something that adds to the question here.

I have a test function ...

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.editbtn').click(function(){
                $(this).html($(this).html() == 'edit' ? 'modify' : 'edit');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and a table

```
<table>
  <tr><td><button class="editbtn">edit</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td><button class="editbtn">edit</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td><button class="editbtn">edit</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td><button class="editbtn">edit</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

... and as per [Html table with button on each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528419/html-table-with-button-on-each-row) and http://jsfiddle.net/tXS6w/ I should be getting some cool "edit" <=> "modify" text changing action going on ... alas nothing!

even if I pop in an alert("hello world") in the function nothing happens. So my detective powers say that it is not being loaded.

It may be obvious, but I'm new to the javascript land :-)

Comment: Have you included jquery in the page with a <script> tag?

Comment: The fiddle you referenced has jquery included by selecting it in the options on the left, but when you write your own page, you have to include jquery yourself.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMairose  ... to be truthful ... no I did not on that page as it turned out ... however after adding in           <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>      I get same non behaviour

Comment: I'm not sure how the Scala Play Framework works as far as using @routes.Assets.at. I would ensure that is pulling the correct path, and double check for any typos, because the code you posted works.

Comment: I would think that the " in @routes.Assets.at would end the beginning " of your src attribute. Try using single quotes inside the at method like: <script src="@routes.Assets.at('javascripts/jquery-1.7.min.js')" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: well yeah , so I'm pretty certain there are no typos because the same style include is used on another page which has a similar function which works ( this was part of a template website rather than me coding it ) .. in fact I'll post that in better format below

Comment: Ah .... all good thanks ... basically it was your initial Answer Andrew :-)   ... In my various attempts at solving the issue I'd removed " $(document).ready" from the function definition ... many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```js
$('.editbtn').click(function() {
              $(this).html($(this).html() == 'edit' ? 'modify' : 'edit');
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="editbtn">edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="editbtn">edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="editbtn">edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button class="editbtn">edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: example of working page  `<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/tms-0.4.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/menu.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slider')._TMS({
                show: 0,
              :  progressBar: false
            })
        });
    </script>`

Comment: Wow, you ask one question a year. Seems like you are a good Googler.

Comment: Ha ha, well soon to change. That's 2 JavaScript ones in a few weeks. Front end just ain't my game but I promise to read a book in it 