# JS Created buttons are not defined when accessed later

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a script that makes a button in a table every 5 seconds.
I originally had the button made with the `onclick` attribute which called a function in the script. This however, gave me an error saying that the function didn't exist, and as from what I've seen on here, it has been answered but I don't know how I'd fix it in my situation. I switched it so that Javascript handles for the button click. I added attributes to the button tag to grab when the `btnTeamListAction` function is called. The console prints the following,

> control.js:86 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
>   at window.onload (control.js:86)

JS Snippets:

```
  #button click handler
  btnTeamListAction.onclick = function(){
    var id = this.getAttribute("data-team-id");
    var isRedo = this.getAttribute("data-is-redo");
    teamListSelect(id,isRedo);
  }
  #the function that creates the buttons
  function appendTeamTable(id,name,finished){
    var finished_txt;
    var action_content;
    if(finished == 1){
      finished_txt = "Yes";
      action_content = '<button id="teams-list-action" data-team-id="'+id+'" data-is-redo="1">Retime</button>';
    }
    else {
      finished_txt = "No";
      action_content = '<button id="teams-list-action" data-team-id="'+id+'" data-is-redo="0">Time</button>';
    }
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML ='<td>'+ id +'</td><td>'+ name +'</td><td>'+ finished_txt +'</td><td>'+ action_content +'</td>'
    teamTable.appendChild(tr);
    var btnTeamListAction = document.getElementById("teams-list-action");
    btnTeamListAction.onclick = function(){
      console.log("ActionClicked");
      var id = this.getAttribute("data-team-id");
      var isRedo = this.getAttribute("data-is-redo");
      teamListSelect(id,isRedo);
    }
  }
```

I've tried browsing this form for this error and have found many related questions but not for this particular case with the button being created by JS itself.
Please ask if you need the full script or HTML, Thanks!

Comment: `javascript:void(0)` is old school... What are you trying to do?

Comment: That's a underlying question I had that now that I think about it I don't really need the `a` tags. I'll update the post in a sec. What I'm trying to do is have a function (requiring the `team-id` and `is-redo` parameters) be called when the button is pressed. Like I said though, using the `onclick` attribute dosn't work.

Comment: The error `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at window.onload...` seems to indicate that the variable `window` is null. You'll have to show more code because the section you posted doesn't seem relevant to the error you are receiving.

Comment: Ok I'll post more code, but please pardon the inefficiency of it all. I have to have it working by Monday.

Comment: Wow, dude! This is a bit scary, to be honest... Why so many `getElementById`, `onclick` and so on? I think you should refactor your code and try to keep in mind the KISS philosophy. I'm sure your problem will become obvious when you'll have a clean codebase. Make this effort, it's worth it. :)

Comment: And that's why I only gave a snippet. I don't have the time to refactor the code like I normally do.

Comment: OK. If you don't have time to refactor, just try to replace `window.onload` with an IIFE. In other words, remove `window.onload` and put your code inside `(function () {})();`. Tell me if you get the same problem...

Comment: If it doesn't work, try to replace `window.onload` with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {});`.

Comment: It got significantly worse. Now none of the code works at all. I tried instead using the JQuery equivalent `$(document).ready(function(){...});`. It gave me a warning and error both saying the same thing.

Comment: I see... This is a strange behavior, but there are many issues in your code. I'm afraid this debugging question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528419/html-table-with-button-on-each-row) and took the idea from the second answer and put a event handler on the table itself instead of the buttons individually. It's works like a charm now. Thanks all three of you for attempting to look through my seriously messed up code! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function appendTeamTable(id,name,finished){
    var finished_txt;
    var action_content= document.createElement("a");
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.setAttribute("id","teams-list-action");
    btn.setAttribute("data-team-id",id);

    if(finished == 1){
      finished_txt = "Yes";
      var t = document.createTextNode("Retime");
      btn.setAttribute("data-is-redo","1");
    }
    else {
      finished_txt = "No";
      var t = document.createTextNode("Time");
      btn.setAttribute("data-is-redo","0");

    }

    btn.appendChild(t);
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
      var id = this.getAttribute("data-team-id");
      var isRedo = this.getAttribute("data-is-redo");
      teamListSelect(id,isRedo);
    });
    action_content.appendChild(btn);
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(action_content);
    tr.innerHTML ='<td>'+ id +'</td><td>'+ name +'</td><td>'+ finished_txt +'</td>'
    tr.appendChild(td);
    teamTable.appendChild(tr);}
```

Comment: Did that. Still getting that pesky error. Rest of the code still works though.

Comment: are you sure you have an element with id="teams-list-action"

Comment: yes. look under the function `appendTeamTable`. `<button id="teams-list-action" data-team-id="'+id+'" data-is-redo="0">Time</button>`

Comment: that element is not there yet it is injected after the ajax call of `ajaxGetTeams`

Comment: add this ` var btnTeamListAction = document.getElementById("teams-list-action");
  btnTeamListAction.onclick = function(){
    var id = this.getAttribute("data-team-id");
    var isRedo = this.getAttribute("data-is-redo");
    teamListSelect(id,isRedo);
  }` at the end of `appendTeamTable` function and remove the first code from the script

Comment: please see if the error is referring to same element (the previous error was at line 86 and refers to the element with id  teams-list-action)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
    at control.js:86`

Comment: have you deleted the the event listener at line 86 and the selector at line 10 after moving them to `appendTeamTable` function ?

Comment: Ok did that. Error is gone but the button dosn't do anything when clicked. I'll update the code above.

Comment: I did do exactly that.

Comment: sorry for that, i took some time to recreate the function  in the new edit please replace it with your function and let me know if it work