# How to Take user input by clicking on the specific area of html text and html table content using Microsoft Bot Framework V4 template using C#

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I am developing a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework. And I have enabled HTML rendering to show tables in the webchat channel. Now I want to do something like:

When I click on the table row or content of a cell or a defied text block or HTML list item it will work like a button and the bot should listen to the click and get the value of the clicked text block and show the next result. Also if possible to set value against the specific clickable area.

In the below code I have set `html:true` so that webchat channel will render HTML in the chatbox.

```
const markdownIt = window.markdownit({ html: true, linkify: true, typographer: true });
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
  directLine: directLine,
  renderMarkdown: markdownIt.render.bind(markdownIt),
  styleOptions          
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

From the bot I have send HTML like this

```
text = "<p>Here is the table result:</p><table class=\"botTable\"><tr> <th> Name </th><th> Id </th><th> Age </th></tr> <tr><td> Prime </td><td> S360 </td><td> 25 </td></tr> <tr><td> Jon01 </td><td> J460 </td><td> 22 </td></tr> </table>";

await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(text), cancellationToken);
```

Here is the sample table:

[image: Sample HTML Table]

I am very new in bot framework please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean you have "enabled HTML rendering to show tables in the webchat channel"? This sounds very unusual. Can you explain why you have done that and post code and screenshots so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @KyleDelaney  I have set `html:true` to enable HTML rendering

`const markdownIt = window.markdownit({ html: true, linkify: true, typographer: true });`

GitHub link: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2289

Comment: Would you be willing to use Adaptive Cards instead of a Markdown table?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I don't want to use the adaptive card. And when we click on a search result, I want to show a full webpage in the bot window so I have to use HTML and the table is an HTML table.

Comment: Then can you show us a sample message that the bot would send to Web Chat to render the table?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I have edited my post and added a sample that how bot send HTML to Web Chat to render the table.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Delaney Thank you for your answer, I think it will work "reinventing the wheel" but I can not achieve the goal. I have to do some more R&D

Comment: Would you go ahead and upvote and accept my answer? You can ask new questions if you hit any roadblocks

Answer (score 1):

### You should use an Adaptive Card

The Bot Framework already has builtin ways for a bot to send buttons to the client so that the client sends a message back to the bot when the user clicks a button. One such way is with [Adaptive Cards](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/). I cannot stress enough that if you try to build your own solution instead of using Adaptive Cards, especially as a beginner, you are doing things the wrong way. Adaptive Cards are [extensible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/extensibility), so if you find that you can't get a card to look the way you want out of the box using column sets, you can create your own element that renders whatever HTML you want. You can use an Adaptive Card for your "table" with buttons and then still have your bot send the next message as raw HTML.

#### If you really insist on reinventing the wheel...

You can create [custom components](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/05.custom-components/e.card-components) in Web Chat that your bot can use by sending attachments instead of HTML text. Whatever buttons you create in the component can send messages back to the bot using [Redux actions](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/d.post-activity-event). There are several actions that would work in your case, like `WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT`. You can reference the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/packages/core/src/actions) to see all the available actions.

Supposing you don't want to do that either and you just want to keep having your bot send raw HTML to the client, you can use [onClick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) events but you'll still need to use Redux actions to have your event handlers send messages to the bot. [You probably shouldn't be using tables at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics#:~:text=HTML%20tables%20should%20be%20used,to%20contain%20the%20footer%2C%20etc.), but if you must use tables then you might be interested in this question about putting buttons in tables: [Html table with button on each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528419/html-table-with-button-on-each-row)